# NSIS Interacting with C# or VB?

Tags: sql, sql-server, nsis

Im looking for a way to possibly interact with C# or VB with NSIS. The idea is to do some Validation of a user through a database. (Basically check to see if user exists) when doing the installer.

Since I don't think NSIS can interact with Microsoft SQL Directly but C# could, what would be the easiest way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSIS itself can only call NSIS plugins (A DLL with function exports in a specific format)

The [system plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/System/System.html) can call any normal WinAPI (stdcall/cdecl) function in Windows or 3rd-party DLLs.

To use .NET stuff you need to use the [CLR plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Call_.NET_DLL_methods_plug-in)...